# How to make SQL Query with Two Different Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot fine same question in here, so I write it.

I need one SQL query for below details;
I have two tables and 2st table has team_id and 2nd table have home_team_id and away_team_id and home and away scores.

I can make home and away matches separately as below queries already:

**Home Matches Query :**

```
SELECT Distinct m.week,m.match_date, h.team_name as Home, a.team_name as AWAY,m.home_score,m.away_score,m.league_id
FROM matches m,teams h,teams a, leagues l
WHERE h.team_id=m.home_team_id and a.team_id=m.away_team_id
and h.team_name ='Real Madrid'  and m.league_id = 1;
```

**Away Matches Query :**

```
SELECT Distinct m.week,m.match_date, h.team_name as Home, a.team_name as AWAY,m.home_score,m.away_score,m.league_id
FROM matches m,teams h,teams a, leagues l
WHERE h.team_id=m.home_team_id and a.team_id=m.away_team_id
and a.team_name ='Real Madrid'  and m.league_id = 1;
```

**I want to see one team home and away results in same query.**

My Tables are: (matches and teams)

**matches** *table columns are;*
**match_id
match_date,
home_team_id,
away_team_id,
home_score,
away_score**

**teams**  *table columns are;*
**team_id,
team_name**

**I want to see below result :**

One team’s Home and Away score in one table as

Example: **Team is Real Madrid**

Results:

| Home Team | Away Team | Home Score | Away Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Real Madrid** | Barcelona | 1 | 0 |
| **Real Madrid** | Cadiz | 1 | 1 |
| **Real Madrid** | A. Madrid | 2 | 2 |
| Villareal | **Real Madrid** | 2 | 0 |
| Valencia | **Real Madrid** | 1 | 3 |

Comment: Why do you have the `league` table in the queries? You never use it.

Comment: I have different leagues so I can filter with like this. leagues table has league_id and league_name columns only.

Comment: But you're not using `l.league_name` in the query. And you have no joining condition for the `league` table, so you're creating a cross product with all leagues.

Comment: You need `l.league_id = m.league_id` in the query if you want to use the `league` table.

Comment: If you use ANSI JOIN syntax it becomes more obvious when you've forgotten the joining criteria with a table.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same query, but test the team name against either `h.team_name` or `a.team_name`.

```
SELECT Distinct m.week,m.match_date, h.team_name as Home, a.team_name as AWAY,m.home_score,m.away_score,m.league_id
FROM matches m
JOIN teams h ON h.team_id=m.home_team_id
JOIN teams a ON a.team_id=m.away_team_id
WHERE 'Real Madrid' IN (h.team_name, a.team_name) and m.league_id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar it works. For league_id is also in matches and teams table. I didn't mentioned  So your answer is worked properly that so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join two tables with teams table and matches table. Use OR paramater instead of AND.